# returning an array of individual chars

Tags: c, arrays, char

I'm currently working on a university project where I'm making a game in c. I'm trying to make a selection of button based menus and need to be able to get the text into a few different menus. I'm trying to use a switch case based function to return the text for the buttons.

```
char * findButtonTxt(int reference) {
    char *rtnTxt[] = { NULL };

    switch (reference) {
    case 1:
        rtnTxt[] = { "T", "O", "W", "E", "R", "_", "O", "F", "_", "P", "O", "W", "E", "R", NULL };
        return rtnTxt;
        break;
    default:
        return "T", "O", "W", "E", "R", "_", "O", "F", "_", "P", "O", "W", "E", "R", NULL;
    }
}
```

I want it to use it like this

```
    txt = findButtonTxt((4 * curMenu) + i + 1);
    betterText(20, (getmaxy() - (25 + (50 * i))) - 30, txt);
```

this is what I have so far, I need it to return the array this way because it's the only way I can get the text to display using the version of BGI I have.

This is what is currently working.

```
    char *twrTxt[] = { "T", "O", "W", "E", "R", "_", "O", "F", "_", "P", "O", "W", "E", "R", NULL };

betterText((getmaxx() / 2), 0, twrTxt);
```

Sorry for the long question.
thanks for the help in advanced.

Comment: why not `return "TOWER_OF_POWER";` -- make `findButtonText` return `const char *`

Comment: `char *rtnTxt[] = { NULL };` is declared local to `findButtonTxt`. When the function returns, `rtnTxt` no longer exists. You can do `char *rtnTxt;` and then `rtnTxt = "TOWER_OF_POWER";` and `return rtnTxt;` to return a *Pointer To the String Literal*.

Comment: @MFisherKDX I wish i could do it that way, but the version of BGI my Lecturer gave me will only work with it the way I showed, and even that took 2 weeks and the help of several lab helpers to get to.

Comment: Unfortunately, the way you showed won't work. See comment by @David

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming C based on the code.

You can't return a stack allocated array as a pointer.

```
 char *rtnTxt[] = { NULL }; //Don't do this
```

You should malloc an array and then use strncpy

```
#define MAX_STRING 256 // modify this to what ever your max string will be
char *rtnTxt = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_STRING);
```

Then down in your switch you can strcpy

```
strcpy (rtnTxt ,"What I want to copy");
```

Then return the result

```
return rtnTxt;
```

Here is the complete solution

```
#define MAX_STRING 256
char * findButtonTxt(int reference) {
    char *rtnTxt = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_STRING);

    switch (reference) {
        case 1:
        strcpy (rtnTxt ,"Tower of power");
        break;
    }
return rtnTxt;
}
```

Finally don't forget to call **free** when you are done or you will have a memory leak :)